# HIT won't submit

Tags: mechanicalturk

(This is a very basic newbie question)

I created a HIT and started a batch, adding enough funds to allow for 10 assignments.  When I submitted the batch, it takes me to the "manage" tab and displays "status: in progress" with a yellow status bar (I presume that means 0% submitted).  It's been stuck that way for nearly a day.

How do I determine what's blocking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a newbie with mturk, it can be confusing.

Upon doing a few more batches, I discovered that the bar is first pink while the HIT is being published.  This takes several seconds, then it turns yellow.  As "workers" complete "assignments", the bar progresses to green.

So, if it stays yellow for a long time, that means people aren't seeing it (too low on search results) or are choosing not to participate.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has not been completed by any worker yet.

You can search Mechanical Turk for your requester name [here](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/findhits?match=false) to see if this is the case.